# If i = 0, why does i++ = 0?

Tags: javascript

Please can someone explain to me why if i = 0, i++ returns 0 and not 1:

```
let i = 0;

console.log(i++); // returns 0
console.log(i++); // returns 1
console.log(i++); // returns 2
console.log(i++); // returns 3
```

Sorry in advance if this seems like a dumb question!

Comment: Post-increment operator does exactly what its name says.

Comment: take a look to [Arithmetic_Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators)

Comment: now do  `console.log(++i)`

Comment: Thank you very much all!